# How to move an image when it is clicked on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm currently making a Javascript/HTML/CSS game and I need a specific image to move one pixel to the side when that image is clicked. Here's my code for each part:

```
<input id="test" type="image" src="https://discussions.apple.com/___sbsstatic___/migration-images/200/20011164-1.gif" alt="SUBMIT"></input>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:227px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function () {
    // stuff should hopefully be going here soon!
};
```

I'm using Bootstrap and JQuery 2.x (edge).

Comment: are you using canvas? If you're just moving an HTML element you can just update its CSS properties

Comment: Canvas? And how do I update its CSS properties?

Comment: Let a = some HTML element. You can set the style using a.style.left = 10px.

Comment: [<canvas>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) element, is a html element that allows drawing graphics.

Comment: linstantnoodles' suggestion worked amazingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can update an elements CSS like so:

```
$("#test").on("click",function(){
  $(this).css("left","1px");
});
```

This is a simple answer to a simple question. If you're making a game, there may be a more indepth way to tackle your mechanics. But this is jQuery syntax to do what you asked.

Comment: You may need to return false from the click function to avoid a postback which would erase the moving of the input image.